# Looping object returning a nil instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looping under my comment model to display all the post comments

```
 %h2 Comments
 - @post.comments.each do |comment|
     %p
       %strong Comment:
     = comment.text
     = link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

that's returning me these
[image: Nil comment in the end]

As you can see there is one blank object, if I go to the rails console and check all the comments that post has, it tells me that it just has two comments 'Comment 1' and 'comment2'
Any ideas why is instantiating a nil object and displaying it as if it exists?
Here's my comments controller create action

```
def create
  @post = Post.find_by slug: params[:post_slug]
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Error'
  end
end
```

If the post does not have comments, it does not display any nil comment, it just happens if I have comments in that post
Show action for PostController

```
 def show
  @post = Post.find_by slug: params[:slug]
  redirect_to posts_path unless @post.present?
  @post.update_visit_count if @post.present?
 end
```

Comment: What does your `index` action look like?

Comment: or your `show` action from `PostsController`?

Comment: Edited answer with show action, could it be because I'm searching for the post twice?

Comment: Do you have any validations that prevent the `comment` from being saved without the `text` attribute?

Comment: I think that at the moment you are able to create `comment` with a nil text attribute thus you're getting the extra comment.

Comment: On my model I have the validates presence set to true, I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed point.Every posts have comments so firstly do nested each loop e.g. 
`@posts.each do |post|
      post.each do |comment|
        ....
      end
end`

Comment: No there's no need to do that under the show action, cause I'm just displaying 1 post not  all posts,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like template issue. In HAML indentation matters. Loop content should have indentation 2 more spaces than looping command. But in your view the line `%p` is shifted by 4 characters relative to the previous one, not by 2 as it should be.

Could you replace that template code with this:

```
%h2 Comments
- @post.comments.each do |comment|
  %p
    %strong Comment:
  = comment.text
  = link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

and try again?

Comment: That’s weird. I think your post really has 3 comments then. Add ```comment.id``` to the template to verify that.